# Django Schema Reverse Related Objects

Tags: python, django, orm, django-ninja

I have the following two Django models:

```
class Participant(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    sport = models.TextField()

    bookmaker = models.ForeignKey(Bookmaker, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("name", "bookmaker", "sport")

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name} ({self.sport}) | {self.bookmaker.name}"

class BookmakerParticipant(models.Model):
    sharp_participant = models.OneToOneField(
        Participant, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, 
        related_name="sharp_participant_match"
    )
    soft_participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        Participant, related_name="soft_participant_matches"
    )

    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

In my schema definition I'd like to access all the `BookmakerParticipant` objects where the `Participant` is in `soft_participants` from the `Participant`s perspective. Thus, I created the following schema:

```
class UnmatchedParticipantSchema(ModelSchema):
    bookmaker: BookmakerSchema
    soft_participant_matches: BookmakerParticipantSchema

    class Meta:
        model = Participant
        fields = [
            "name",
            "sport",
            "bookmaker",
            "soft_participant_matches"
        ]
```

However, this creates the following error in Django

```
ninja.errors.ConfigError: DjangoField(s) {'soft_participant_matches'} 
are not in model <class 'core.models.Participant'>.
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [resolver](https://django-ninja.dev/guides/response/#resolvers):

```py
class UnmatchedParticipantSchema(ModelSchema):
    bookmaker: BookmakerSchema
    soft_participant_matches: list[BookmakerParticipantSchema]

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_soft_participant_matches(obj):
        return list(obj.soft_participant_matches.all())

    # ...
```